# Dynamic routing and rendering a pug

Tags: node.js

I have a question, how to render for example a pug file when you have route like this?

```
router.get('/user/:id/edit', function(req,res,next){
....
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried  `res.render()`?

Comment: Can you be more precise? Ye, I have tried this, but probably don't know how to realize

Comment: `res.render('somefile.pug')`...?

Comment: Oh ok, that helped, i was thinking the hard way, thanks...